# Collecting output of a cloud formation template using java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am writing a AWS Cloud formation template to create a S3 Bucket resource and that template returns the ARN of the newly created S3 bucket. that template is working fine on AWS Cloud Formation Web console. but i need to deploy that template using AWSCloudFormationClient in Java. There it is not producing that output.. Help me to get out of this..

Here's the code

```
    String stackId=createStack("MyS3Bucket");
    System.out.println("Stack Created Successfully with "+stackId+"Stackid");
    DescribeStacksResult results=cloudFormation.describeStacks();
    List<Stack> stacks=results.getStacks();
    System.out.println("Stacks "+stacks);
    for(Stack stack:stacks)
    {
        System.out.println(stack.withStackId(stackId).getOutputs());
    }
```

Thanks & Regards